# Adding a link in row of Bootstrap table in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am looking to make the entire row of my Bootstrap table clickable as a link in Ruby on Rails. Can anyone help me out on this?

As far as I understood from other posts here, I need to install Jquery code and use a class in my table tag. If so, what kind of code would it be and where do I need to place it?

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>City</th>
  </tr>

<% @offers.each do |offer| %>
<tr>
  <td><%= offer.company %></td>
  <td><%= offer.city %></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_offer_path(offer) %></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'Show', offer_path(offer) %></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', offer_path(offer),
                method: :delete,
                data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>

</tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: What if you just do it like this `<li><%= link_to offer.company, company %></li>` ?

Comment: Thanks, that worked!